# How to install and configure an HP printer on Ubuntu?

Tags: printing, hp, hplip, cups-lpd

I have an `HP` printer model `Deskjet 3516`.

I remember having deleted some folder from the printer settings by mistake, but I can not remember which folder it was.

I tried adding a printer by system settings, as shown in the following figure, but it did not work.

[image]

I have already tried to reinstall the printer using `hplip` and the `hp-setup` command as follows:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
┌─[ricardoramos]@[falcon]:~
└──> $ sudo hp-setup
[sudo] password for ricardoramos: 

HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.14.3)
Printer/Fax Setup Utility ver. 9.0

Copyright (c) 2001-13 Hewlett-Packard Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

Searching... (bus=usb, search=(None), desc=0)
error: No PPD found for model deskjet_3510 using old algorithm.
error: No appropriate print PPD file found for model deskjet_3510_series
Searching... (bus=usb, search=(None), desc=0)
error: No PPD found for model deskjet_3510 using old algorithm.
error: No appropriate print PPD file found for model deskjet_3510_series
error:  Printer queue setup failed.   Error : Unable to connect to CUPS server

Done.
```

I have already tried all the alternatives, but nothing is working, what can be happening? Does anyone have a solution?